# <li> element class change, using DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, element

I would like to make the `<li>` element to change the class when I click on it, and when I click one more time to remove it. I have used simple code like this :

```js
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

ul.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var li = document.querySelector("li");
  li.classList.add("done");
})


ul.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
  var li = document.querySelector("li");
  li.classList.toggle("done");
})
```

so as you can see on click it goes on and on dbl click it goes off, but it is working on all the `<li>` elements at once.

Comment: There's no markup in your question -> [mcve]; And what does _"it is working on all the `<li>` elements at once"_ mean? Your click handler will only ever change the first `<li>` element in the DOM.

Comment: fyi `dblclick` is clicking the mouse twice in succession not clicking again on item that has been clicked once.  Based on your problem description, your code will not toggle the class like you expect.  You should change the `add` in the listener to `toggle`

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the class to the event's target.

```js
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

ul.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.target.classList.add("done");
});

ul.addEventListener("dblclick", (e) => {
  e.target.classList.toggle("done");
});
```

```css
.done {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Sebastian I'm glad you're happy! If my answer helped you, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the event listener on the UL, which will impact all LI inside.
Another options - you can set the event listener on the LI instead.

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");

lis.forEach(li => {
    li.addEventListener("click", function(ev){
        ev.target.classList.add("done");
    })


    li.addEventListener("dblclick", function(ev) {
        ev.target.classList.remove("done");
    })
});
```

```css
li {
  color: lightgray;
}

li.done {
  color: green;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3jcbaqgu/17/

Comment: I understand now !! thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to select the right element when you click on it using `event.target`.

```html
<ul id="my-list">
    <li>Item #1</li>
    <li>Item #2</li>
    <li>Item #3</li>
</ul>
```

```js
const list = document.querySelector('#my-list');
list.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

    // The clicked element
    const target = event.target;

    // Make sure the clicked element is an <li> element
    if (target instanceof HTMLLIElement) {
        // Toggle class
        target.classList.toggle('done');
    }
});
```

Useful documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target